# Why can quorum change when adding new nodes to Cassandra?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

I doubled the size of our cluster from 3 nodes to 6 nodes. We have RF=3. Also this is Datastax Enterprise 4.8.0 `cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.9.791 | DSE 4.8.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3`

I'm rebalancing the cluster and now we're seeing some weird errors from our application:

`ERROR: core.RequestProcessor.logRequest()    Could not log request 4d96f06a-b465-4608-904f-2014a271d507 for brand 5954: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency QUORUM (3 replica were required but only 2 acknowledged the write)`

How can 3 replica be required when RF=3? Shouldn't quorum be 2? Also, disk usage has really ballooned on the nodes. Is this expected?

Comment: Your node is still UJ isn't it? Think about the scenario where that bootstrap fails. You need the writes in both the new node and the old replica don't you?

Comment: I waited until all 6 nodes were UN before I started to rebalance the cluster using OpsCenter. These are search nodes, so I'm not using vnodes. One node is UM (moving) at the moment.

Comment: Would the same concept apply when a node is UM? The writes would be necessary in both the old and new replica/node?

Comment: Yeah, it would apply.